# Rails how to render array field in template use form_builder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using mongoid, and i save the geo location info in an array field.

In my model, I have:

```
field :location, :type => Array
```

In my view, I have:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :location %>
```

And this gives the result:

```
<input id="foo_location" name="foo[location]" type="hidden">
```

What I want is like below:

```
<input id="foo_location_1" name="foo[location][]" type="hidden">
<input id="foo_location_2" name="foo[location][]" type="hidden">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution by setting `:multiple => true`, which will give the right result.

```
<%= f.hidden_field :location, :multiple => true, :id => "foo_location_1" %>
<%= f.hidden_field :location, :multiple => true, :id => "foo_location_2" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for the `location` param to be passed back as an array, you have to explicitly define the input name for these fields:

```
<% @foo.location.each do |loc| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :location, :name => "foo[location][]", :value => loc %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The form is for new object, so `@foo.location` is empty.